# Programmatically How to wipe out data remotely in android apps

Tags: android

I am developing an application for security purpose which has 1 requirement as "Wipe out data completely if device is stolen".

While doing search for this functionality, I came across one application "Find My android phone" here which supports this feature of "remotely wipe out all data".(https://www.google.co.in/android/devicemanager?u=2)

But i want to this functionality through programmatically in my app.Can someone give me a solution for this problem?

And is it possible to do this functionality through programmatically?

Comment: have you got any solution for this